# Lazy evaluation of "composed" default variable in dependent Ansible role

Tags: ansible

I have two Ansible roles, let's call them `postgres` and `myservice`.

In my `postgres` role, I define a few default variables (in `postgres/defaults/main.yml`):

```
postgres_db: pgdb
postgres_user: postgres
postgres_systemd_docker_service_name: postgres_{{postgres_db}}
```

In my `postgres` role, I create a systemd service unit file from the `postgres_systemd_docker_service_name` variable. The idea here being that if I want to run more than one postgres docker containers for multiple services, I can distinguish them using the `postgres_db` variable.

Then I have the `myservice` role, in which I depend on the `postgres` role and override some of the default variables.

In my `myservice/meta/main.yml`:

```
dependencies:
  - {role: docker}
  - role: postgres
    postgres_user: "myservice_user"
    postgres_password: "myservice_password"
    postgres_db: "myservice"
```

However, when I run a playbook that uses the `myservice` role, it will create my systemd unit files as `postgres_pgdb` (which is the default value) rather than as `postgres_myservice`.

If I use the `postgres_systemd_docker_service_name` variable in my `myservice` role, it gets evaluated as `postgres_myservice`.

Is there any way for me to ensure that the composite variable in my `postgres` role is evaluated in such a way that my `myservice` role can override the default values?

Comment: You use `db_name` in `postgres` role defaults, but supply `postgres_db` as parameter... Seems like a typo.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Thanks for pointing that out... unfortunately it's just a typo here in my question (not in the actual role). So the problem still exists. I'm getting around it by basically duplicating all the postgres variables in myservice. So for each `postgres_variable1` I have in the `postgres` role, I have a `myservice_postgres_variable1` and in my `meta/main.yml` I set all the postgres variables to their myservice counterparts. But I'll fix the question so that the typo isn't there.

Comment: What ansible version do you use? If there's no typos in your case, this setup works fine in 2.2+.

Comment: hmm... I'm using 2.2.1.0. I'll check and see if there is something more subtle going on by simplifying my ansible role that I'm actually using.

Comment: I am afraid we need more information about the role "postgres". This looks like a variable precedence issue caused by something else than the default variables. Are you sure there isn't an `include_vars` hidden somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Trying a small example, I found that (using Ansible 2.4) a composed default variable (i.e on that is in the `defaults/main.yml`) will only be interpolated when that default value is used for the first time.

Example, using only a single role:

`roles/certs/defaults/main.yml`

```
---
certs_dir: /etc/pki/tls/certs
cert_files:
  - "{{ ssl_domain }}.crt"
  - "{{ ssl_domain }}.key"
  - "{{ ssl_domain }}_ca-bundle.crt"
```

`roles/certs/tasks/main.yml`

```
---
- name: Determine the subdomain for the current host
  command: hostname --domain
  register: domain_result

- name: Set domain name as fact
  set_fact:
    ssl_domain: "{{ domain_result.stdout.strip() }}"

- name: Download certificates
  get_url:
    url: "http://{{ intranet_certificate_host }}/{{ intranet_certificate_path }}/_.{{ ssl_domain }}/{{ item }}"
    dest: "{{ certs_dir }}"
  with_items: "{{ cert_files }}"
```

This will work. I see this is not involving a "dependent" role, but as facts work like that across roles, I am nigh certain this will work across roles just as well.
So, at least in the version that I used, lazy evaluation is the default behaviour, you only need to combine it with `set_fact` to provide the value that goes inside the composed default.